# Retrieve my personal site url

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile-service, user-profile-property, jsom

This code retrieves my property values succesfully except my "PersonalUrl" property. If i cant retrieve it with the PeopleManager object, is their any other options to retrieve the personal url property?

```
 var profilePropertyNames = ["SPS-HireDate", "PreferredName", "PictureURL", "PersonalUrl", "WorkEmail"];
                var userProfilePropertiesForUser = new SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser(ctx, userAccount, profilePropertyNames);
                var userProfileProperties = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(ctx).getUserProfilePropertiesFor(userProfilePropertiesForUser);
                ctx.load(userProfilePropertiesForUser);
                ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
                  userProfileProperties[0 1 3 ... etc]..
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [getPropertiesFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj712745.aspx)

```
var profilePropertyNames = ["SPS-HireDate", "PreferredName", "PictureURL", "WorkEmail"];
var userProfilePropertiesForUser = new SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser(ctx, userAccount, profilePropertyNames);
var userProfileProperties = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(ctx).getUserProfilePropertiesFor(userProfilePropertiesForUser);

var personProperties =  new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(ctx).getPropertiesFor(userAccount);
ctx.load(personProperties,'PersonalUrl');

ctx.load(userProfilePropertiesForUser);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {

    var mySiteUrl = personProperties.get_personalUrl();

  userProfileProperties[0 1 3 ... etc]..
});
```

Take a look the [SP.UserProfiles.PersonProperties object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj712733.aspx) for available properties.

Answer (score 0):

In my user profile the field name looks to be "PersonalSpace" not "PersonalUrl".  Maybe try that? [image]

Comment: Thats the personal space.. I need my site